# How can i allow Google App Engine to connect with VM Instances

Tags: google-app-engine, networking, apache-kafka, external, ping

I have a java spring boot application deployed on Google App Engine. In the beginning i was trying to connect this app with a VM intance that is running the Apache Kafka.

After suffer decided try a ping command on internal and external IP and i receved a negative response, when a tried at my PC i got positive response. So a decided create a socket command to connect it with google page, and it didnt work.

So, i am sure that my Google App Engine doesnt allow external comunication. Anyone knows something about?

Answer (score 0):

GAE have limit in oubound request, you can see here .`[outbound-requests][1]`

The port range:

- 80-90
- 440-450
- 1024-65535

So ping maybe not a good try. You may try to use java URL to test you connection.